# ListView + DataPager controls do not maintain state

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listview, viewstate

I have a `ListView` control and a `DataPager` control applied to it (the `DataPager`'`PagedControlID` is set to the `ListView`'`ID`).

It happens that I bind the `ListView` to a datasource of mine (an array) in this way:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

   if (!this.IsPostBack) {
      MyType[] x = ...; /* Returns an array of MyType */
      this.MyLV_ListView.DataSource = x;
      this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind();
   }

}
```

I start and go to the page, it pages! but when I select another page everything is empty, I mean there are a certain number or entries, but repeated regions are empty.

If I remove the post back condition, it is ok!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

   MyType[] x = ...; /* Returns an array of MyType */
   this.MyLV_ListView.DataSource = x;
   this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind();

}
```

Why is this?
I cannot load everything again, it is something I would really like to avoid....

Thankyou

NOTE: Even setting `EnableViewState` to `true` in both `ListView` and `DataPager` does not affect anything.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this blog post: [ASP.NET DataPager not paging after first PostBack](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/12/14/ASPNET-DataPager-not-paging-after-first-PostBack.aspx)

Here are a couple more things you can try:

**Databind during the OnPreRender event**

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind();
    base.OnPreRender(e);
}
```

**Try handling the ListView's PagePropertiesChanged event**

```
MyLV_ListView_PagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.MyLV_ListView.DataSource=someDatasource;
    this.MyLV_ListView.DataBind()
}
```